# Use Gong.DragDrop to drop to Non-ItemsControl like UserControl

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

I am trying to use the Gong.DragDrop Lib to drag from a ListBox to arbitrary UserControls. But dragging over those is always showing the not-allowed-symbol. I can see the code inside the github repository, where separate paths are created. I just do not understand why this doesn't work. Dragging to an ItemsControl-Derived control works without problems. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks guys!

Comment: Well... debugging it, I saw that you cannot drop on something by default that does not offer a "target collection". I will try to implement a custom drop handler. Lets see how this works out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the answer is you can do it. You just need to implement a custom DropHandler and assign it to the DropTarget. I used a StaticResource to create the handler and assign it to the UserControl with

```
dd:Gong.DragDrop.DropHandler="{StaticResource customDropHandler}"
```

The CustomDropHandler looks like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;
public class CustomDropHandler : IDropTarget
{
    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        // Not done yet...
    }
}
```